# Problem with memory usage measurment

Tags: c#

I have some C# functions, and I want to measure their memory usage in bytes. I used GC.GetTotalMemory as follows:

```
long val1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

// my code

long val2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

long result = val2  - val1 ;
```

I tried to pass both true and false as argument for GC.GetTotalMemory, but I do not know why I get negative result value, when I subtract val1 from val2 .... Another issue is that GC.GetTotalMemory give different values in each excution, I think it is not accurate

Can anyone know why I get a negative result value ? is it because of the argumenet (true or false), although I tried them both and got negative result value too

Can anyone know why I get different values in each excution of the C# function ?

Please if anyone has a better efficient way to measure memory usage in bytes for C# function in Windows, please tell me and thanks alot

Comment: Just **don't**.  If you have memory issues, use a profiler.

Comment: It means it is working properly.  It also means that you really shouldn't do this, whatever you get is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

You may be receiving a negative result, because a garbage collection could have taken place between the two points, causing the total memory consumed to decrease. In fact, when you pass true to the `GC.GetTotalMemory` function, [you're actually allowing it to wait for a garbage collection to take place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx), thus increasing the likelyhood of a negative value being returned.

A better (and more accurate) way to do this, assuming you can suspend the process at points, is to look at various (.NET and Process/Memory) counters in Performance Monitor, to see the before and after.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think GC.GetTotalMemory is helpful to determin the amount of memory allocated by a certain method, the GC could have been doing anything in the meantime and the results are not reliable.

Can't you use a profiler to identify the memory allocation of the program, either the VS 2010 profiler, or ANTS profiler from RedGate, free for 2 weeks I think.

Notice there are also utilities from sys internals useful to check the allocated memory of a program, working set or something similar.