# Measure memory used by code

Tags: c#, c++, c, optimization, performance

I would like to make better some methods in C# or C++ or C.
To measure time I can use Stopwatch class, but additionally I would like to measure memory reserved by exterminated code. Do you know any class or method which has similar properties to MemoryMeasure class used in code below?

```
Stopwatch s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
MemoryMeasure m1 = MemoryMeasure.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
//some compute
//for example
//var x = new LargeObject(new SmallObject(), 45);
//some compute
//some compute
}
m1.Stop();
s1.Stop();

Console.Writeline("Your code was executed in " + s1.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
Console.Writeline("Your code ate " + m1.UsedMemory + "MB of memory");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use a memory profiler - there are several free and commercial tools.

[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [Ants memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) are two popular commercial ones.

There are [a few free ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler) as well.

Comment: What's the problem with using [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13039467/284240), could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4738030/1583) for a reason (basically, a GC cycle could happen between the points of measurement, making the value negative and meaningless).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use GC.GetTotalMemory static method, but I'm not sure measuring memory this way is a good idea. Memory profiler is much better option

Comment: Oded is right, GC is not a something you could rely on, its work is rather unpredictable, so there is no guarantee you would receive a correct value each time calling GetTotalMemory in same conditions.